# When is a point considered inside/outside a polygon?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, polygons

Are the vertices of the polygon considered to be inside of the said polygon?
Also, how about points intersected by the edges of the polygon?

Comment: Are the half-lines defining an angle part of the angle? It is a matter of mathematical taste, I guess. On the other hand, like *positive means positive*, one might argue that *inside means inside*, i.e. in the interior, so the vertices (or the sides) of a convex polygon *do not* belong to the interior of the polygon.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Though in Barry Simon's five volume treatment of analysis, he starts volume 1 by indicating that *positive* means *nonnegative*, and *strictly positive* means *positive*.  There really is no accounting for taste. ;)  That being said, "inside" usually means "interior," which usually means $A \setminus \partial A$ (where $\partial A$ denotes the boundary).

Comment: @XanderHenderson: that comes as a shock to me, I liked "*positive means positive*" as a motto for *positive means $>0$*. I guess I will replace *positive* by $>0$ in all my future answers :D

Answer (score 1):

Within discrete and computational geometry,
a polygon $P$ is usually defined to include its boundary $\partial P$.
So then the vertices and points on edges are "in" $P$.
Often the phrase "strictly interior" to $P$ is used to indicate a
point in $P$ but not on $\partial P$; a boundary point is "on" (not "in")
the boundary $\partial P$.

Sometimes a polygon is defined to be just the vertices and edges, and other
times to be the closed region of $\mathbb{R}^2$ bounded by $\partial P$.
Generally authors try to make clear their assumptions to avoid ambiguity.